# How to sync with Mavan with Play 1.2.5

Tags: playframework

I have a Play 1.2.5 application, and it has been deployed for a few years. However, I needed to update my server to the newest Ubuntu version and reinstalled.

Now however, when I do play deps --sync I get the following warning.

> SERVER ERROR: HTTPS Required url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/maven-metadata.xml

How can I specify that it should use HTTPS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @cbley I got on the right track. Play! uses Ivy, so after a bit of digging I found that it is possible to edit/create the file:

> ~/.ivy2/ivysettings.xml

Here you can set a resolver, so I put in:

```
<ivysettings>
  <settings defaultResolver="chain" />
  <resolvers>
    <chain name="chain">
      <ibiblio name="securedcentral" m2compatible="true" root="https://repo1.maven.org/maven2" />
    </chain>
  </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, just realized I read the question wrong.

You probably can use some iptables magic and a proxy to access the HTTPS endpoint.

---

Short answer: you cannot.

You either need to switch your URLs to use HTTPS, or use the insecure endpoint `http://insecure.repo1.maven.org/maven2/`

See here: https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041287334-Central-501-HTTPS-Required

Comment: Do you mean there is no way to add some parameter to the dependency.conf file to redirect all request either to the https or the insecure endpoint?

Comment: I don't know Play 1 enough to definitely answer how, you could probably define maven central with HTTPS as a custom repository: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2/dependency -- that might work.

Comment: Thank you. I found the solution along that line, and answered it myself, but will accept your answer if you post it.