# Error building scala project with IntelIJ and SBT

Tags: sbt

I am getting an error while building a scala project with intelIJ on a Mac machine.

```
sbt --version

sbt version in this project: 1.3.8
sbt script version: 1.3.
```

Below is the error I am getting in the IDE and bunch of packages are not downloaded.

```
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.3.8 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#routes-compiler_2.10;2.3.8 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.4 ...
[info] Resolving commons-io#commons-io;2.0.1 ...
[error] SERVER ERROR: HTTPS Required url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/2.0.1/commons-io-2.0.1.pom
```

Iam not sure where the http url is picked up, on searching i got a command to list the resolvers for sbt and it does show https

```
sbt:root-0-13> show externalResolvers
[info] * FileRepository(local, Patterns(ivyPatterns=Vector(${ivy.home}/local/[organisation]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)([branch]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]), artifactPatterns=Vector(${ivy.home}/local/[organisation]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)([branch]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]), isMavenCompatible=false, descriptorOptional=false, skipConsistencyCheck=false), FileConfiguration(true, None))
[info] * public: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/
```

Can someone share some info on how to resolve this error ?

Comment: What's the output of `show resolvers`?

Comment: `sbt:v2> show resolvers
[info] *` 

This is what i see with resolvers

Comment: Oh, you are using a really old Play version which probably adds those resolvers to the project build. What's inside your .sbt files in `project`? Maybe this could work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60157744/4432837

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59763435/access-maven-repo-over-https-in-sbt#comment106274751_60079797

This one helped for me. didnt have ~/.sbt/repositories file, Added maven-central as mentioned there and it worked

Comment: Thanks @cbley for helping out !!